# Servo motor and EMI noise on peripheral devices (microcontroller)

Tags: transformer, noise, grounding, servo, emi-filtering

I have 6 servo motors (DELTA  ASD-A2-0121). Peripheral devices are affected by EMI noise (When motors are in on state and have no movement). I have changed the ground system from series mode to parallel as Pic1, although noise is slightly reduced but still affects microcontrollers. What else should I do to remove noise? Is isolation transformer effective?

Update 1:

Pic2, 3, 4, 5 are voltages of a microcontroller pin, when it's pulldown (Pic 2, 3) and when it has a PWM signal as output (Pic4, 5).

Motor power supply: 220-230 VAC, 1 ph, 1.6 A, 100 W
Microcontroller supply: 5 VDC, 3 W, supplied via USB 3 port.

Update 2:

[1. Oscilloscope probe link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_transformer)

2. Grounding system is under 7 ohm.
3. servo drives are connected to [ethernet motion control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FypxS.jpg) and motion control is connected to PC via ethernet cable and communication protocol is mode bus (Pic 6.)

Update 3:

Microcontroller is [This camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwWoi.jpg) and it's block diagram is shown in Pic 7. Camera (microcontroller) provides some output control signals.
Image of probe setup is added as Pic 8.

Update 4:

I used a 220v  1KW [isolation transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_transformer) and there is less noise now. See  Pic 9, Pic 10.

update 5:

System connection image added.

[image]
Pic 1. Serial and parallel ground connection.

[image]
Pic 2. EMI noise using series ground connection on a microcontroller pin (pulldown) when motor is in ON state.

[image]
Pic 3. EMI noise using parallel ground connection on a microcontroller pin (pulldown)  when motor is in ON state.
[image]
Pic 4. A microcontroller pin voltage (PWM signal as output) when motor is in ON state.

[image]
Pic 5. A microcontroller voltage (PWM signal as output) when motor is in OFF state.

[image]
Pic 6. servo drivers are connected to X,Y,Z AXIS of motion control and motion control is connected to PC via ethernet cable(mode bus communication).

[image]

Pic 7. [Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwWoi.jpg) (microcontroller) block diagram.

[image]

Pic 8. How probe is connected to camera outputs.

---

I used a 1KW [isolation transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_transformer) on main power of servo drivers and now there is less noise than before. It's shown in below pictures.

[image]
Pic 9. Camera/microcontroller output (output port is pull down) with isolation transformer (up) and without it (down).

[image]
Pic 10. Camera/microcontroller output (pulses as output) with isolation transformer (up) and without it (down).

[image]

Pic 11. System connection.

Comment: Where (precisely) and how (exactly) are you measuring what is shown on the o-scope? There is no room for compromise or imprecision when answering this.

Comment: @Andyaka It's a voltage of a microcontroller pin when motor is in ON/OFF states.

Comment: Instead of taking pictures of the oscilloscope screen, you can directly save the images in a USB drive attached to the oscilloscope. That would be a very clean image containing all the data currently being displayed on the screen. Please consider doing that.

Comment: Please show your probe setup. Please show schematic and layout. What's your groundplane and decoupling situation?

Comment: Are you measuring with a low inductance probe (spring clip)? Circuit diagram and PCB layout ? How exactly are the micro's affected?

Comment: @winny, servo drivers are connected to motion control directly, and motion control is connected to PC. All grounds are connected in parallel to ground system.

Comment: @Unimportant, One microcontroller sends some pulses to another, more pulses are counted by second microcontroller (or when there is no pulse noise is considered as pulse) when servomotors are in ON state.  Probe link is added.

Comment: Suggestion re: pictures - there's nothing wrong with pics in my opinion, but if you hold the camera level with the screen, it will be easier to read the bottom, which has the critical scale information.

Comment: industrial PLC system components like that tolerate a surprising amount of noise on the 24V. That said it can't hurt to improve the power supply. If you're adding a microcontroller to the situation, filter the microcontroller's supply well, and consider opto-isolating the signal?

Comment: So there is really not anything micro controller about it, you are using an off the shelf PLC? Also, show probe setup!

Comment: I don't get where are those microcontrollers and how they are connected in the system?

Comment: Which probe is of secondary importance. HOW do you connect it?

Comment: @AbdullahBaig, You are right, I don't have the extension cables.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič,  Actually microcontroller is a camera which I added it's block diagram (see update 3).

Comment: @ probe image added.

Comment: In general your probing setup is flawed for any high speed measurement but your scope is in ms-range, so your noise is broad band all the way down in frequency. How’s the local power supply decoupling on the service driver?

Comment: *servo. Damn you autocorrect!

Comment: @winny, It was directly connected to servo. An isolation transformer is used as power supply.

Comment: What’s the _decoupling_ situation on the driver?

Comment: @winny, Sorry I don't get it, Do you want to know the connection of wires to servo drive?  Main power is connected to a circuit breaker and then connected to driver terminal. In datasheet it's recommended not to use any decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Oh! That’s good. Can you draw in all connections to and from it in a simplified diagram? Is your supply to it floating but you have some ground connection elsewhere which lets out lots of cable conducted EMI? Is the servo driver grounded?